# What is Migrate Android Code?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch 
 cases. Invoke this fix to get more information. whats the reason this is used for?[image]

Comment: Could you link to the "fix" you're referring to? Your question is confusing.

Comment: This question is totally confusing. a fix is to fix things. if you are using switches with resources ids, they don't work anymore because of the ids not being final. so it fixes the errors that come from that. As it seems to be explained in the document you refer to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the official blog post about this:

http://tools.android.com/recent/switchstatementconversion

http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Basically, resource constants in library projects are no longer "final".  From the ADT Site:

> In other words, the constants are not final in a library project. The
>   reason for this is simple: When multiple library projects are
>   combined, the actual values of the fields (which must be unique) could
>   collide. Before ADT 14, all fields were final, so as a result, all
>   libraries had to have all their resources and associated Java code
>   recompiled along with the main project whenever they were used. This
>   was bad for performance, since it made builds very slow. It also
>   prevented distributing library projects that didn't include the source
>   code, limiting the usage scope of library projects.

Answer (score 17):

For all of those who didn't resolve this problem yet - this is what i`v done:

1. Go to your "project.properties" file.
2. Delete this line " android.library=true"

The reason why i had this problem, was because i did a copy&paste the properties file into my project (was missing).

cheers.