# Android - retrieve string array from resources

Tags: android, string, resources

Below is the code that i made to retrieve the string array item:

```
String[] menuArray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

 // Create an ArrayAdapter that will contain all list items
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    menuArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu); 


    for(int i = 0; i < menuArray.length; i++) 
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(menuArray[i]);
        ll.addView(b);
    }

    this.setContentView(sv);
 }
```

This is the strings.xml file:

```
 <string-array name="menu">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        </string-array>
```

However, the ***R.array.menu*** having this issue to compile:
As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases. 
Invoke this fix to get more information.

Comment: Yeah, i can provide you snapshot from emulator if you want to see. I just skipped the use of variable **x** along with try catch block as definition of **count()** is not provided.

Comment: Are you using  switches with resources ids? check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387777/what-is-migrate-android-code)

Comment: i solve it d.. it is just because i move out the app_name from the strings.xml LOL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0;i<menuArray.length; i++) 
{
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(menuArray[i]);
    ll.addView(b);
}
```

Delete the below statement

```
 try {
        x = count();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and try to give layout height and width to all Layouts..

Comment: i have update the code above. But still having the same issue for the R.array.menu.

Comment: Take a separate arrays.xml and take string array t<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
     <array name="testArray">  
    <item>first</item>  
    <item>second</item>  
    <item>third</item>  
    <item>fourth</item>  
    <item>fifth</item>  
     </array>
    </resources>here

Answer (score 92):

How to retrieve a string array from resources:

*array.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="my_string_array">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Code

```
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);
```

*(The OP already had their question answered but based on the question title, other people may come here looking for this answer.)*