# String Resources

Tags: android, arrays, string

i'm practising how to add an string to the addapter of the spinner. If i declare the string in the java activity, works perfectly, but if i do in the string.xml:

```
<string-array name="tabs">
    <item>tab</item>
    <item>tab1</item>
    <item>tab2</item>
    <item>tab3</item>
    <item>tab4</item>
    <item>tab5</item>
</string-array>
```

and in the java

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterr1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.tabs);
```

dont work.

what's the problem? Thanks

This is the full code, because i have problems whit the app (crash)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner OptionSpinner;
    TextView textview;


    String[] stabs= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        OptionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.OptionSpinner);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stabs);

       adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        OptionSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

        OptionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textview.setText("seleccionado: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                if(position==1){
                    Intent IntentActT1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActTab1.class);
                    startActivity(IntentActT1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: The array adapter class takes a list as its final parameter. Not a resource integer.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532907/android-retrieve-string-array-from-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String[] stabs= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
 ArrayAdapter adapterr1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stabs);
```

**Edited 1**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner OptionSpinner;
TextView textview;
String[] stabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OptionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.OptionSpinner);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    stabs= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stabs);

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    OptionSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

    OptionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            textview.setText("seleccionado: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            if(position==1){
                Intent IntentActT1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActTab1.class);
                startActivity(IntentActT1);
            }
         }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


 }
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but the app crash

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, int)` doesn't use the third argument as an array resource id; it uses it as the id of the `TextView` to use to display each item in the layout. Instead, you can pass `getStringArray(R.array.tabs)` as the third argument (or `getContext().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)`, if this code is not in an `Activity`).