# Android R.Java Reserved Workd Final disappeared from my variables

Tags: java, android, static, final, r.java-file

i had this code

```
 public static final class id {
        public static final int LinearLayout1=0x7f090007;
        public static final int LinearLayoutVentas=0x7f09003a;
        public static final int RelativeLayout1=0x7f090026;
        public static final int TextView01=0x7f090014;
        public static final int TextView011=0x7f090021;
        public static final int TextView02=0x7f09000b;
        public static final int TextView021=0x7f090018;
        public static final int back_button=0x7f090059;
        public static final int barcode_image_view=0x7f090042;
...
}
```

now it is

```
 public static final class id {
        public static int LinearLayout1=0x7f090007;
        public static int LinearLayoutVentas=0x7f09003a;
        public static int RelativeLayout1=0x7f090026;
        public static int TextView01=0x7f090014;
        public static int TextView011=0x7f090021;
        public static int TextView02=0x7f09000b;
        public static int TextView021=0x7f090018;
        public static int back_button=0x7f090059;
        public static int barcode_image_view=0x7f090042;
...
}
```

then now i got this error

**As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases. 
 Invoke this fix to get more information.**

at here

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {


    case R.id.informacion: /*error is in this line*/

        onDetailCliente();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

then i delete r.java and I rebuild but they i have this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387777/what-is-migrate-android-code

Comment: Use the fix, so the `switch` is converted into an `if-else`-statement.